# Select an item from the list,

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is just a demo. I need to alert "HI" when I click in `Reports` whose id is `main_menu_reports`.

Here's what I tried.

```
 <ul class="nav" id='main_root_menu'>
     <li id='main_menu_dashboard' class='active'><a href="{% url 'cilantro_dashboard' %}"><span class="icon-picture icon-white"></span> Dashboard</a></li>
     <li id='main_menu_reports'><a href="#"><span class="icon-briefcase icon-white"></span> Reports</a></li>
     <li id='main_menu_billing'><a><span class="icon-film icon-white"></span> Billing</a></li>
 </ul>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function(){
  $("#main_menu_reports").click(function(){
    alert("kkkkk")
  });
});
```

I dont know where I'm going wrong. I've been doing this in the past, but its not working.

Comment: It works here: http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/AEsB2/

Comment: It worked for me: http://jsfiddle.net/La64S/

Comment: Yaa...It kind of absurd. I dont even get a bug in firebug.

Comment: Are you sure you have loaded jQuery (but even if you havent you should get an error in Firebug. Can you provide some more information about your setup?

Comment: check for the jquery library it is included properly or not

Comment: Make sure you are not having [same id](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20535117/1777090) for more than one element in whole page

Comment: whether the element is loaded dynamically... is your script within a dom ready handler... any error in your console

Comment: I'm SORRY everybody. I didnt included that JS file. SORRY.

Comment: Its a request, everyone please remove your answers. I want to delete this stupidity of mine. Thanks

Comment: This question have answers, hence I cannot.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your span class is covering the id. So try targeting just the class or id with class like so.

```
$(function(){
  $("#main_menu_reports .icon-briefcase").click(function(){
    alert("kkkkk")
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<ul class="nav" id='main_root_menu'>
     <li id='main_menu_dashboard' class='active'><a href="#"><span class="icon-picture icon-white"></span> Dashboard</a></li>
     <li id='main_menu_reports'><a href="#"><span class="icon-briefcase icon-white"></span> Reports</a></li>
     <li id='main_menu_billing'><a href="#"><span class="icon-film icon-white"></span> Billing</a></li>
 </ul>
```

Here is [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hicurin/C9SFc/)

Comment: It does not works on my system, nor it gices me any error on firbug

Comment: As you can see it's working fine on jsfiddle. So did you include jquery to your page?

Answer (score 0):

You can use .on("click" in new jquery

or old jquery try .live("click"

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#main_menu_reports").on("click", function(){
alert("kkkkk")
});

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add Jquery library in your file `<head>` block

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script>
    $(window).load(function(){
       $("#main_menu_reports").on("click", function(){
       alert("kkkkk")
       });
    });
   </script>
```

OR

```
    $(document).on('click','#main_menu_reports',function () {
        alert("kkkkk")
    });
```